# How to locate cause of "A string is required here" error

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, vb6

Let me start by saying I'm a web developer inheriting a VB6 / Crystal Reports application, and I don't know either very well.

My client was using Access as their database, and I've migrated them to SQL Server. Going back is not an option. I've gotten nearly their entire application working after the migration, but the Crystal Reports are having issues.

I was previously getting an error that said "The server has not yet been opened." In an attempt to fix this, I converted the driver from ODBC to OLE DB. Now I'm getting an error that says "A string is required here." That's it...no stack trace, no Debug button. So I don't know how to track the problem down.

All the other similar questions I've found always have the specific formula that's causing the problem, but that's where I'm stuck. Without a stack trace or Debug button or anything, I have no idea where to look for an error.

So mine is more of a question on debugging strategy than a specific code problem. Where do I look for an error?

If you need code samples, I can provide them, but you'll have to be specific as to how to get any dumps you need to see. I'm using the Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0 editor. I see the error message whenever I right-click on **Database Fields** and click *Verify Database* (it first says "The database is up to date" and then "A string is required here"). I also see the error when attempting to run the actual report in the application.

I've tried going through all of the **Formula Fields** and wrapping database fields in `CStr(...)`, but I still get the error. Where else should I look?

Comment: It's not about converting to string...do you have any if else conditions in formula fields...if yes can you post those will try to resolve

Comment: If you are unable to provide check that both and else should return same datatype...you can't return string in if and integer in else...this is one debugging option as per your question if this doesn't work let me know will try some other debugging option....As you know crystal is very poor in providing correct exceptions

Comment: @Siva - In this scenario, I believe I may have just solved the issue. I found a date field that was being used directly on the report, so I made a formula field that does some conversion and defaulting to ensure it will be a string. But I don't want to add that as an answer because the main question is about **how to find** the error as opposed to the cause of this particular issue. I expect to encounter many more of these errors in the near future. Is there anywhere else to look aside from the Formula Fields?

Comment: Formula fields,select expert formulas,supress conditions,highlight experts,.....in someway or other all thesr come into formula field categories

Comment: Any other tricks? Like "save the report to a Crystal Reports file and open it with the Crystal Reports application, then ..." (do something that makes it magically easier to debug...)? I'm now running into a different issue (as expected) where I get a "No rowset was returned for this table query or procedure," and all questions out there seem to be related to stored procedures and `SET NOCOUNT ON`, but as far as I can tell, I'm not using any stored procedures. I'm using mostly regular tables and one view. Any idea where to look for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience with Crystal, no, there is no magic button to debug a broken report.

I would definitely recommend opening the report in Crystal Reports (as opposed to VB). You'll have to check the usual suspects - start with the database Expert; verify the tables and joins are setup correctly.
Look at the Record Selection formula (Report > Selection Formulas > Record) - use the "Check" button at the top left to verify syntax.

When looking at Formulas and database fields, you can tell if the field/formula is used in the report if the field has a green checkmark next to it. Crystal is 'smart enough' in most cases that it doesn't validate logic if the object is not used by the report - This includes tables. If a table is joined, and links are not enforced, and the table is not used ANYWHERE in the report, Crystal won't even include the table in the SQL query. Just a helpful tidbit. Lastly, you can export the report defintion to a text file - Click export and select "Report Definition" - this can be helpful for searching for fields. Hope that helps.